# 3D Diffusion Equation in Fourier space

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, numerical-analysis, diffusion

I'm solving the 3D Diffusion equation
$$u_t=k(u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz})$$

in MATLAB using Fourier techniques.  I assume a 3D Fourier expansion $(e^{-ipx},e^{-imy},e^{-imz})$of the solution.

Physical space: $u(x,y,z,t)$.
Fourier Space:  $c(m,n,p,t)$.

Substitution and differentiation result in:
 $$c(m,n,p)^{N+1}-c(m,n,p)^{N} = -\frac{k\Delta T}{2} (p^2+m^2+n^2)(c(m,n,p)^{N+1}+c(m,n,p)^{N})$$
after applying a Crank-Nicolson scheme.

I'm using `fftn()` and `ifftn()` to forward my coefficients in time and bring them back to physical space.  However I achieve universal decay from the initial condition to zero with no heat flux in any direction, for all time.  Typical time step: `0.00001`.  Typical `k=0.005`.

Is the problem with my application of `fftn()` or the stability of my finite-difference?

**Edit:**  I've taken an initial condition of $50 \sin(2x)$. I merely took the boundaries of that initial condition and imposed them as the boundary conditions for all time. No good I'm guessing?

**Edit 2:** I forgot the wavenumber squared on the rhs.  Thanks James!

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? if $u(x,y,z,t)=0$ everywhere on your boundaries, $0$ *is* the steady state solution.

Comment: Shouldn't you be multiplying c(m,n,p) by the wavenumber squared on the r.h.s. because of the second derivative?